# Return All Records through a Table Function When NULL Parameter is Passed

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, sql-function, sql-null

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_actions]
(
  @roleid varchar(36)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
  select *
  from actions 
  where action_type_id in (
    select action_type_id
    from action_roles
    where role_id = isnull(@roleid,role_id)
  )
```

The function above returns a list of actions from an actions_roles table that matches the @roleid parameter supplied.  However, there are some actions in the actions table that do not exist at all in the action_roles table.  So when a parameter of NULL is specified, I'd like the function to simply return

`select * from actions`

I tried using an if statement but that doesn't seem to work for inline table functions.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_actions]
(
  @roleid varchar(36)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
  IF (@roleid is NULL)
  BEGIN
    select * from actions
  END
  ELSE
    select *
    from actions 
    where action_type_id in (
      select action_type_id
      from action_roles
      where role_id = isnull(@roleid,role_id)
    )
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply move the check on the nullity of the parameter to the outer query.

This should do what you want, while simplifying the query and possibly making it more efficient (this gives a change to the query planner to not execute the subquery when the parameter is null).

```
select * 
from actions 
where 
    @roleid is null
    or action_type_id in (select action_type_id from action_roles)
```

Note: as commented by Vladimir Baranov, you should probably add `option(recompile)` to this query (it goes at the very end), to force the database to recompute the query plan for each execution, so it can possibly optimize the subquery away when the parameter is null.

Comment: This is a good way to write this query, but I would strongly recommend to use `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` with this type of query. Specifically because the optimal execution plan should be drastically different depending on the value of the parameter. If there is no `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`, then optimizer has to generate a plan that is valid for any possible value of the parameter and therefore can't eliminate the subquery. A very good article to read: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) by Erland Sommarskog

Comment: @VladimirBaranov: yes I think that's a good point. I added it to my answer. Thanks!